# Динамический перевод QT c++

Tags: c++, qt, перевод

Я хочу сделать чтобы все надписи в моём приложении переводились с русского на английский по выбору варианта в QComboBox или по нажатию кнопки. Нашёл инструкцию: https://evileg.com/ru/post/153/ Вроде сделал почти всё как там
MainWindow.cpp:

```
 void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
    {
        if (index == 0){qtLanguageTranslator.load(QString("QtLanguage_") + QString("ru_RU"));}
        else{qtLanguageTranslator.load(QString("QtLanguage_") + QString("en_EU"));}
        qApp->installTranslator(&qtLanguageTranslator);        // Устанавливаем перевод в приложение
    }

void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    // В случае получения события изменения языка приложения
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) {
    ui->retranslateUi(this);    // переведём окно заново
    }
}
```

Mainwindow.h:

```
protected:
    // Метод получения событий в главном окне приложения
    // В нём будет производиться проверка события смены перевода приложения
    void changeEvent(QEvent * event);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTranslator qtLanguageTranslator;
```

.pro:

```
TRANSLATIONS += QtLanguage_ru.ts
TRANSLATIONS += QtLanguage_en.ts
```

Настроил для них переводы, сделал lrelease.
Но дальше не получается поменять язык выбором варианта или вообще установить английский язык (по умолчанию русский). Что я сделал не так? Или есть более простой вариант?

Comment: `qtLanguageTranslator.load(QString("QtLanguage_") + QString("ru_RU")` будет пытаться загрузить файл **QtLanguage_ru_RU.qm** из текущего пути раз полный не указан

Comment: а у вас lrelease судя по всему делает QtLanguage_ru.qm и путь до него желательно полный указать